# Given a sequence $(a_n)_{n=1\to\infty}$ and let $I=(a,b)$ be an open interval so that $\{a_n | n \in \mathbb{N}$ \ {0}} is dense in $I$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to prove or contradict the 2 statements below:

1. Every $L \in I$ is a partial limit of $(a_n)_{n=1\to\infty}$.
2. If $\{a_n | n \in \mathbb{N}$ \ {0}} $\subseteq I$ , then $b = \limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n$ .

If i got this right, then for every two real elements in $I$ (say $c, d \in I$ so that $c  < d$) , there exist natural index of the given sequence which satisfies : $c < a_n < a_{n+1} < ... < d$.

Comment: Why do you believe $a_i$ is monotonically increasing?  Why can't $\{a_i : i \in 0 \bmod 3\} \subset I$, $\{a_i \mid i \in 1 \bmod 3\} \subset [b,\infty)$, and $\{a_i \mid i \in 2 \bmod 3\} \subset (-\infty,a]$?

Comment: @EricTowers Good point.  This definitely complicates the case`s scenarios ! :)